# How To remove white background from pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jquery and ajax to load different pages into my index page. links are targeted to open in a specific DiV and for some reason Every page that I create seems to have this white border at the top. I removed the padding from the css but for some reason every page that I load into the div pops up with white border at the top with the text in it. I want to remove this white border and align the content area to the center. Please help me

[image: Screenshot]

the code is a bit much to post please visit my website for a live view... only working links are Roster, and Labels....

http://www.trillumonopoly.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the `background-color` css rule off `body`.

Also, every major browser has a devtools component nowadays - it is your best friend.

edit: I see that it's applied by bootstrap. You can override it by specifying `body { background-color: none; }`

By the way, I think it's bad practice to apply a background image to the html node. Instead, apply it to the body node.